# How can I call a method of derivitive class within base's class constructor using a pointer to function?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

Disclaimer: I am a C developer and it's my first time that I'm trying something like this in C++. I have zero experience with the language.

I have a class `Bob` that has a pointer to a function `myFunction` as a private member.

I want to inherit the class `Bob` and pass a method of the derived class to the pointer function using the base class constructor.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using FuncHandler = void (*)(int x);

class Bob
{
    protected:
    Bob(FuncHandler x)
    {
        myFunction = x;

        // When I call the function here
        // I get garbage...
        // x value is = 932452288
        myFunction(10);
    }

    private:
    FuncHandler myFunction;
};

class Alice : public Bob
{
    public:
    Alice() : Bob(reinterpret_cast<FuncHandler>(&Alice::foo))
    {
        
    }
    void foo(int x);
};

void Alice::foo(int x)
{
    std::cout << "x value is = " << x << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
    Alice obj1;
    return 0;
}
```

The question is what did I do wrong that I'm getting garbage to the output?

Comment: Make it `static void foo(int x);`

Comment: @Eljay You are right! Thank you !!! Can you post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `using FuncHandler = void (*)(int x);` is a convenient name for a function pointer.

Alice's `void foo(int x);` is not a function, it's a member function.  A member function is a different kind of thing than a freestanding function.

Fortunately, in this particular case, the code does not need to access the function as Alice's member function, it can use a static class function, which is compatible with a function pointer.  Assuming the signatures match, which in this case they do.

Change `void foo(int x);` to `static void foo(int x);`.

Then change `Alice() : Bob(reinterpret_cast<FuncHandler>(&Alice::foo))` to `Alice() : Bob(&Alice::foo)` and the code is all set.

CAUTION:  if the `foo` function needed to access Alice's instance state, it would have problems because at that construction point in the code the Alice object has not been constructed yet.

Answer (score 2):

I see two major issues with your approach.

First, base classes are constructed before derived classes. Inside the base class constructor, the derived class does not yet exist, so calling a non-static member function of the derived class is undefined behavior.

Second, your functional cast is invalid. It works in one sense, but the converted value cannot be used safely. Whenever you feel the need to use `reinterpret_cast`, don't; use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast` instead. While there are some valid uses for `reinterpret_cast`, beginners tend to use it in bad locations. The static and dynamic casts are powerful enough for most needs and weak enough to fail when you try to do something inappropriate, such as your conversion. (Pointer-to-member-function is a different beast than pointer-to-function. While the compiler might allow converting one to the other, it is not safe to *invoke* the function through the converted value.)

You possibly should go back to the drawing board. At the very least, remember to mark member functions `static` if they do not use the `this` pointer. You might be letting your C background cloud your C++ thinking. (Of course, that is guesswork since I do not know your [real problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).)