# C++ Event-Driven State Machines for Embedded Systems

Tags: c++, events, embedded, state-machine

What is the simplest way to implement a state machine in C++?

My first thought was to create an abstract class and derive from it every state machine. Using pointer to functions I can keep track of the current state.

Using the constructor of the derived class I can setup the initial state. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68134339/3829694) shows how I was going to do.

Each method inside the derived class would represent a state.

The next design that popped to my head was to use a `State` class with virtual functions, `onEntry`, `onExit`, `handleEvent`, And a pointer `State * currentState`. However this approach is based heavily on iheritance cause each state must be derived from the class `State`. So, if I have 50 states I will need 50 new classes! I'm guessing that's a lot?

My current implementation in C is just a pointer to a function inside a struct. And under the variable `static state_machine_t state_machine_one` I just define all the functions-states in the same `.c` file. So, when I want to dispatch an event to all my state machines I just put every struct inside an array of pointers and just run a loop. This is what I'm trying to do in C++.

EDIT: The system relies on hierarchical state machines. The current nesting level is up to 8 states. And the executable run on an Cortex-M0 8MHz - 48MHz.

Comment: How complex/simple are your states?  How pure?  How dynamic?  How much overlap?  Are there substates?  Substate machines?  What are your perf constraints; 1 state transition per (frame) (user action) (pixel)?  (ie, Hz, kHz, MHz, GHz?)

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I updates some of the requirements. What do you mean, pure/dynamic and overlap?

Comment: A "pure" function is one without state or side effects; call it with same arguments, get same result.  States are functions, so can be pure or not,  A static state graph has no runtime changes; a dynamic one has runtime changes in the graph itself.  By overlap, do states reuse each otherps implementations?  Or not?

Comment: I highly recommend reading https://www.state-machine.com/psicc/ by Miro Samek, he is an awesome source of state machines and event driven programming.

Comment: @Sorenp I followed his examples to make something similar in C. But it's hard to do the same in C++. He uses tons of macros everywhere

Comment: The book I linked to is his first edition with C++ examples the second edition he uses C.

Comment: @Sorenp I'm gonna have a look at his 1st edition too! Thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest state machine is:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<class...Message>
struct State:
  std::function< State<Message...>( Message... )>
{
    using Base=std::function< State<Message...>( Message... )>;
    using Base::Base;
};
 
int main(){
  State<int> end=[](int x){
     std::cout<<"end\n";
     return nullptr;
  };
  State<int> odd=[&](int x){
    if (x%2) return odd;
    return end;
  };
  State<int> even=[&](int x){
    if (x%2) return odd;
    return even;
  };
  State<int> start=[&](int x){
    std::cout << "Start "<<x<<'\n';
    if (x%2) return odd;
    return even;
  };

    
  int buff[]={0,2,3,5,9,10,33};
  int* inp=buff;
  auto state=start;
  while(state){
    std::cout<<*inp<<'\n';
    state=state(*inp++);    
  }
}
```

A State is a function taking a message and returning a new State.

This doesn't have on enter/on exit, nor states that do not process messages.  If your message is a reference to a queue you can pop off of, you can emulate this easily.