# C++ Assign a member function of a derived class to a pointer to function of the base class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

Following up [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68134339/3829694) about pointers to functions I'd like to ask, what is the difference between the pieces of code below.

This works! I use a pointer to a member function of the class `Base`. Though I have to call the function through the pointer differently cause it's a pointer to a member and not a pointer to a free function. But it works.

```
#include <iostream>

class Base;

using Handler = void (Base::*)(int e);

class Base
{
protected:
    Base(Handler init)
    {
        currentState = init;
    }
    Handler currentState;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base((Handler)&foo)
    {

    }

    void run(int e)
    {
        (this->*currentState)(e);
    }

private:
    void foo(int e)
    {
        std::cout << "foo function\n";
        std::cout << "e = " << e << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Derived derived;
    derived.run(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
foo function
e = 10
```

---

Then I modify the code a little bit and I use pointer to function `using Handler = void (*)(int e);`

```
#include <iostream>

class Base;

using Handler = void (*)(int e);

class Base
{
protected:
    Base(Handler init)
    {
        currentState = init;
    }
    Handler currentState;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived() : Base((Handler)&foo)
    {

    }

    void run(int e)
    {
        currentState(e);
    }

private:
    void foo(int e)
    {
        std::cout << "foo function\n";
        std::cout << "e = " << e << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    Derived derived;
    derived.run(10);
    return 0;
}
```

And it does not work, as you can see from the output below
Output:

```
foo function
e = 679096448
```

Also, Is that legal in C++? Or I have a piece of code that happens to work? I'm asking that because I'm making a state machine model and I wouldn't like surprises in the middle of development down the line...

EDIT: Adding one more question, Why does the function is called, but the argument value is unspecified?

Comment: Just because something works does not mean that it's valid C++. In C++ you cannot convert "a member function of a derived class to a pointer to function of the base class". This is undefined behavior. Forcing the issue by using an explicit cast does not make undefined behavior go away. There is a reason why without the cast the compiler reports this attempt as ill-formed.

Comment: I add the `-pedantic` option and get *warning: converting from 'void (Derived::*)(int)' to 'Handler' {aka 'void (*)(int)'}*, a suggestion that things aren't quite right.

Comment: Side note: Have you looked into using [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)? Could help you simplify.

Comment: Note that `&foo` is not a valid way of getting a pointer to member function. The syntax is `&Derived::food.

Comment: Convert 679096448 into hex and see if it is part of the address of `this` or something strange like that.

Comment: A pointer to a non-member function is simply not the same as a pointer to a member function. Non-member function can be called without an object to be passed to the function as the `this` pointer. A member function *must* be called on an object, which becomes the `this` pointer in the function.

Comment: The key here is to recognize that members of a derived class are not necessarily members of the base class. It goes the other way around: every member of the base class is also a member of the derived class.

Comment: It's legal to convert a pointer-to-member-function-of-derived-class to a pointer-to-member-function-of-base-class, but it is not legal to use it as if it were a pointer-to-member-function-of-base-class. You must convert it back to its actual type when you use it.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use std::function and learn how to use lambdas or std::bind -- I prefer lambdas.

You can define something like this:

```
#include <functional>
using Comparator = std::function<bool(const MyObject &)>;
```

And then you can assign a lot of different things to it. You can define either free or static methods. You can use std::bind in order to assign non-static methods. Or you can do what I do, and use a lambda.

```
void foo(Comparator f) {
    if (f(someObject)) {
     ....
    }
}
```

That part is easy. You can call that like this (for instance):

```
 foo([](const Myobject &obj) { return obj.foo == bar; });
```

Or:

```
 foo([](const Myobject &obj) { return obj.gleep(); });
```

Function pointers are a C-ism. std::function is how to do it in C++. It's more powerful. It can do everything a function pointer can do, but it can go further.

I don't care for std::bind, but you can find examples. Lambda syntax isn't necessarily simple, either, but I prefer it.

Comment: No, `std::function` is not a replacement for function pointers. It does things that function pointers do not do, and there is unavoidable overhead, both in size and speed, to support the extra stuff, even if you don't use it. Function pointers (and pointers-to-member-functions) are lean and mean, and often the appropriate solution.

Comment: function pointers is not a C-ism. Thats very misleading. The first thing that pops to my mind is io-manipulators. Basically the whole `<iomanip>` is about passing function pointers and there would be no good reason to use `std::function` instead of that. Imho a better name would be `std::type_erased_functor` or something like that. `std::function` sounds just too innocent for what it is actually doing